# 「学生生活を楽しむため」とは、旅行や遊び、クラブ活動など、生活を楽しむお金を稼ぐためという意味だ。

Tags: meaning

「学生生活を楽しむため」とは、旅行や遊び、クラブ活動など、生活を楽しむお金を稼ぐためという意味だ。

I know there are 2 main uses of ために
1 - 原因
2 - 目的

Since the above statement 稼ぐ is attached to the ため would the correct use of the statement be 1?
The main cause, origin, source of making a living / working, I use it to enjoy student life.

Is that a correct assessment of the situation at hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have to choose between  原因 and 目的, I wouldn't choose  原因.   原因 indicates the cause of something.  The *objective* is to **earn** money.  So, as an *objective* I would say  目的.

I would translate this お金を稼ぐため as ***in order** to earn some money*.  Likewise, 学生生活を楽しむため as ***in order** to enjoy life as a student*.

クラブ活動 here refers to activity in a school club.  This is not *going to the bars/clubs*.

> 「学生生活を楽しむため」とは、旅行や遊び、クラブ活動など、生活を楽しむお金を稼ぐためという意味だ。

The basic sentence pattern here is

> A とは B という意味だ。

> To say *A* means *B*

This sentence has already been lifted from a larger context.  There seems to be a question about what 学生生活 refers to.  The speaker clarifies that 学生生活 covers things like *trips, hanging out, activities in clubs, etc*.

Sometimes it strikes me that you're applying English word order to Japanese and that will definitely wind up with some confusion for you.

Part *B* here is

> 旅行や遊び、クラブ活動など、生活を楽しむお金を稼ぐため

You start translating this as "In order to make money for..." but then jump to part *A* of the sentence before completing part *B*.  You need to complete *B* that right there and the completion is

> In order to make money for travel, hanging out, club activities, etc"

That is the *B* portion of the sentence.

The *A* portion just says

> 学生生活を楽しむため

which we can render in English as

> In order to enjoy life as a student

I would also advise you to try to stick to as close a literal translation as you can while you're trying to master Japanese.  You translated portion *A* as

> in order to to have a great students life

which is decent colloquial English, but it's deviating too far from the Japanese.

So, here are my two suggestions for you as you're learning Japanese

1. Be mindful of Japanese word order
2. Stick to as literal a translation as possible--this will help you better to master the underlying grammar which initially can be tricky if you're thinking in English (or another language with a very different word order for sentences).

Comment: "In order to To make money for, in order to to have a great students life of travelling, playing, going out to clubs"  Is that correct putting it all together?

Comment: @fynxgloire Sometimes it strikes me that you seem to be applying English word order to Japanese and that will definitely wind up with some confusion for you.  "In order to make money for..." you need to complete that right there and the complition is "... travel, hanging out, club activities et".